# Electron downloading file - Windows Defender Popup

Tags: electron

I'm trying to make an update app feature for an electron app I'm working on. I am able to download the installer for the update, but when I try to run the installer I get this message:

[image]

Is there something that I need to do in order for the installer to not be flagged as unsafe?

Side Note: When I download the installer using chrome, it works just fine. But when I download it using my electron app, it shows that windows defender popup.

Answer (score 0):

Sign your installer package to avoid smartscreen filtering. https://github.com/electron/windows-installer#sign-your-installer-or-else-bad-things-will-happen

Comment: If the only reason is that I didn't sign it, then why does it not get smartscreen filtered when I download it through chrome?

Comment: windows security have various different internal checks either completely block or let it warn to user to decide further action, etcs. You can't know for sure which one is which.